# mongoose filter by multiple conditions and execute to update data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am wondering what would be the best approach to make schema functions using mongoose. I have never used this so the way I think is somewhat limited, same goes for looking for docs, without knowing what's available, is not very efficient.

Through docs I found that either using findOneAndUpdate might solve the problem; but there are some constraints.

Here is the code I am planning to run:

models/Bookmark.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const bookmarkItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    restaurantId: String,
    cachedAttr: {
        name: String,
        latitude: Number,
        longitude: Number,
    },
})

const bookmarkListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    listName: String,
    items: [bookmarkItemSchema],
})

const bookmarkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    },
    lists: [bookmarkListSchema],
})

// const add = (lists, userId) => {
//     let bookmark = Bookmark.findOne({userId})
//     bookmark.lists.listName === lists.listName //current, new
//         ? bookmark.lists.items.push(lists.items)
//         : bookmark.lists.push(lists)
//     return bookmark
// }

mongoose.model('Bookmark', bookmarkSchema)
```

Routes/bookmark.js

```
router.post('/bookmarks', async (req, res) => {
    const {lists} = req.body
    console.log(lists)
    if (!lists) {
        return res.status(422).send({error: 'You must provide lists'})
    }

    let bookmark = Bookmark.findOne({"userId": req.user._id})
    if (bookmark.lists.listName === lists.listName){
        let item = lists.items
        bookmark.lists.items.push(item)
        await bookmark.save()
        res.send(bookmark)
    }

    try {
        // const bookmark = Bookmark.add(lists, req.user._id, obj)
        // await bookmark.save()
        // res.send(bookmark)
        let bookmark = Bookmark.findOne({"userId": req.user._id})
        if (bookmark.lists.listName === lists.listName){ // THIS IS UNDEFINED. How to get this object?
            let item = lists.items
            bookmark.lists.items.push(item)
            await bookmark.save()
            res.send(bookmark)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(422).send({error: e.message})
    }
})
```

The req.body looks like this:

```
{
  "lists": {
    "listName": "My Saved List",
    "items": {
      "restaurantId": "abcdefg",
      "cachedAttr": {
        "name": "abcdefg",
        "latitude": 200,
        "longitude": 200
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically what I commented out in the models/Bookmark.js file is what I would really like to do.

If the userId's list name already exists, then I would like to just add an item to the list.
Otherwise, I would like to add a new list to the object.

What is the best approach for doing this? Is there a straight forward mongoose api that I could use for this problem? or do I need to make two separated function that would handle each case and make that as schema methods and handle it in the routes file?

Comment: `bookmarkSchema.methods.add = function(lists, userId){ /* do your stuff */ }`

Comment: @ippi In the function it appears that the model is not recognized, so when I do `Bookmark.update` within, it does not recognize that Bookmark model. I am clearly missing out something important...